# difference between jsonp and jQuery.support.cors for cross domain request ? also why i can't POST data in jsonp request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

i wrote and test my code in local knowing that cross domain request are tricky but i just forgot that . 
now i want to publish my code it got me .

so i did a little research and apparently i have two options

> 1 - using jsonp dataType and callback function
>   2 - simply adding
>   jQuery.support.cors = true  and crossDomain: true to my ajax code

ofcurse second options seems much easier and i don't need to modify my code as much , but what are the drawbacks ? i mean i'm guessing there are some advantages in using jsonp ? i have to mention my server side code returns a json object to the request

another question ,  why can't i use POST method to send data in my jsonp request ?

```
$.ajax({
 url:'".base_url()."site/remote_group_like/' ,
 dataType: 'jsonp', 
 jsonpCallback: 'getResources' ,
 type: 'POST',
 data: {url : url , domain : domain} , 
 success:function(data){
 },
 error:function(){
 },
});
```

i have put `type: 'POST'` in the code  but it keeps sending a `GET` request ? 
and why it doesn't show the ajax request being send in the fire bug ?

Comment: You need to learn what JSONP is. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: should also look in API to see what `crossDomain: true` is used for. Need to use `GET`. It appears you are trying to hack your way around browser security restrictions and will fight an uphill battle

Comment: Did you get the difference between CORS and JSONP?

Comment: @Bergi not really ! all i know for some reason CORS doesn't work for me ! i went with JSONP anyway